# Protobuf-Net always deserializes an empty list

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

The following code shows how I am trying to serialize/deserialze a List using Protobuf-Net. Method `getNewItem()` returns an object of `ItemsStore`, which is added to the List.

```
// Create an empty list
private ItemsStoreList text;

// Add some elements to the list
lock (text.SyncRoot)
{
    text.AddItem(getNewItem());
    text.AddItem(getNewItem());
    text.AddItem(getNewItem());
}

// Serialize
var file = File.Create("testfile.bin");
Serializer.Serialize<ItemsStoreList>(file, text);

// Deserialize
ItemsStoreList textNew = Serializer.Deserialize<ItemsStoreList>(file);
```

After I run this code, the list contained in object `textNew` is always empty. Object `textNew` is instantiated from class `ItemsStoreList`, which is shown below:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ItemsStoreList
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private List<ItemsStore> m_listData;

    private readonly object m_SyncRoot = new object();

    public ItemsStoreList()
    {
        m_listData = new List<ItemsStore>();
    }

    public void AddItem(ItemsStore item)
    {
        m_listData.Add(item);
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return this.m_SyncRoot; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return m_listData.Count; }
    }

    public ItemsStore getItem(int idx)
    {
        return (ItemsStore)m_listData[idx];
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        m_listData.Clear();
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ItemsStore
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public myStruct m_Text;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ulong m_Time;

    public ItemsStore(myStruct newText, ulong newTime)
    {
        m_Text = newText;
        m_Time = newTime;
    }

    public myStruct Text
    {
        get { return m_Text; }
    }

    public ulong Time
    {
        get { return m_Time; }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct myStruct
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public uint var1;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public byte var2;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public byte[] var3;

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public string var4;
}
```

Comment: Just additional, but note that the "mutable struct" thing is actually easier to solve than you might think, thanks to protobuf-net's automatic tuple handling: if the type has no proto attributes, but has a constructor with parameters that exactly match the public members, it assumes the constructor demonstrates the intent; for example: http://pastie.org/9409395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I note is that you have not rewound the stream; adding this (between serialize and deserialize) changes the behaviour:

```
file.Position = 0;
```

We now get an exception relating to the `ItemsStore` constructor, so we can instruct protobuf-net to ignore that constructor completely:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class ItemsStore
```

Now we get 3 items back:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(textNew.Count);
```

which outputs:

```
3
```

Further probing shows that it is most likely fetching the other data too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textNew.Count; i++)
{
    var item = textNew.getItem(i);
    System.Console.WriteLine(item.m_Text.var1);
    System.Console.WriteLine(item.m_Time);
}
```

I will, however, add the obligatory warning about mutable structs and public fields.